# How to debug %post with rpmbuild

Tags: redhat, rpmbuild

I'm building an RPM that needs to run a number of scripts to configure it after it's been installed to complete the installation. I have to run the scripts in the %post section because the configuration is dependent upon the type of host. All this is fairly easy and well, but every time I run into a bug with the %post section, I have to rebuild the entire package which takes about 20 minutes. Is there a way to skip recompiling everything and just build a new package with just the changes from %post?

Answer (score 1):

If your spec file doesn't create a random build directory and won't delete that build tree afterwards, the more time consuming compiling can be omitted by make. I.e. Similar to not using the `--clean` option in rpmbuild.

You can then also use the [`--short-circuit`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/ch-rpm-b-command.html#S2-RPM-B-COMMAND-SHORT-CIRCUIT-OPTION) flag to rpmbuild to skip the first stages in building.

Comment: According to the man page, --short-circuit only works with -bi and -bc. To test the %post section, I need to use -bb or -ba to build the actual package.

Answer (score 0):

Is the script doing something different when run manually vs. run from the RPM install? You can make a test RPM that has no `%post`, then manually run the script under test (as root). Do this on every host type that needs to be tested until you think you got it. *Then* add it as the `%post` and give it a try.

Comment: I've done that for most of my testing. However, it's RPM macros that I was trying to test that made it difficult to test. Those could only happen during rpmbuild time, afaik.